# Higher-order asymptotics of generalized hypergeometric function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, asymptotics, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

I have a question about higher-order asymptotics of generalized hypergeometric functions. According to https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4
the following is well known:
$$
_2F_1(a,b;a+b;z)\sim -\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\log(1-z),\ \ 
z\rightarrow1^{-}.
$$
My collaborator was able to coax Wolfram Mathematica into giving a higher-order estimate
$$
_2F_1(a,b;a+b;z)\sim -\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\left[\log(1-z)+\psi(a)+\psi(b)+2\gamma\right]+\mathcal{O}((1-z)\log(1-z))
$$
as $z\rightarrow 1^{-}$ for $a$ and $b$ real and positive and where $\psi(z)$ is the digamma function and $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Can anybody provide me with any reference or a hint of why the above Mathematica estimate would be correct?

Comment: See references mentioned here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/184829/454

Comment: @GeraldEdgar the link you gave me was super useful! I am going over  Evans and Stanton's paper regardless of the answer I accepted which is sufficient for the result we are trying to push through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Abramowitz and Stegun, Formula 15.3.11, the equation reads for $m=0,$
$${}_2F_1(a,b,a+b) = -\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{(a)_n (b)_n}{n!^2}(1-z)^n \Big( $$
$$\log(1-z)  -2\psi(n+1) +  \psi(a+n) + \psi(b+n) \Big)$$
Your asymptotic approximation is the $n=0$ term.

Comment: It is actually formula 15.3.10 I needed but that is a cosmetic error. You gave me exactly what I needed. I didn't want to edit your answer. Maybe I have a different edition of the  Abramowitz and Stegun.